# In what way are capital increases usually advertised?

Tags: equities, investment, capital-structure

I am currently trying to better understand capital increases and dilution. I came across a few presentations of companies. I am trying to find out, if there are any standards, which are commonly part of these advertisements.

Obviously, companies usually show an overall cash flow, balance sheet, and P&L forecast/plan. But are there any other "must haves" to attract potential investors?